# Send only endpoints can't publish messages NserviceBus 5.2

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I am using SendOnlyBus with NserviceBus 5.2
and my set-up code is like

```
busConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence,StorageType.Subscriptions>();
                busConfiguration.AssembliesToScan(AssembliesToScan);
                busConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
                busConfiguration.PurgeOnStartup(false);
                busConfiguration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
                return Bus.CreateSendOnly(busConfiguration);
```

and web.config

```
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig,       NServiceBus.Core" />
<section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig,  NServiceBus.Core" />

<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="XXX" ErrorQueue="XXX" NumberOfWorkerThreads="X" MaxRetries="X" />
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="X" Endpoint="X" />
      </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>

<add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Data Source=XXX;database=XXX;User ID=XX;Password=XXx;" />

<add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect" />
    <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
```

this leads to error while publishing message.

> Cannot publish on this endpoint - no subscription storage has been
>   configured."

If i use Memory Persistence, it works fine but not with Hibernate 
DB-Subscription, Not able to find out what's missing or wrong.
Appreciate any help ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

NServiceBus is not configuring subscription persistence because you have asked for a send only endpoint.

Send only endpoints do not have an input queue, which means they have no way to receive and store subscriptions. Trying to Publish makes no sense if you have no subscribers.

Either

- keep the send only bus, but switch from using `Bus.Publish()` to `Bus.Send()`

or

- use a complete bus by calling `return Bus.Create(busConfiguration)` instead of `return Bus.CreateSendOnly(busConfiguration)`

### Code sample

The only code needed to publish an event with NHibernate as subscription persistence on **NServiceBus 5.2.0** and **NServiceBus.NHibernate 6.1.2** is the following:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Features;
using NServiceBus.Persistence;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
        busConfiguration.DisableFeature<TimeoutManager>();
        busConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Subscriptions>();

        using (IStartableBus bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration))
        {
            bus.Start();
            bus.Publish(new SomeEvent());

            Console.WriteLine("Published an event");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class SomeEvent : IEvent {}
}
```

**app.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence" connectionString="Data Source=.;database=database;User ID=user;Password=password;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect" /> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, the application intended to both publish and send messages, I tried using   Bus.Create   but still getting same error.In addition i also tried adding     <add name="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Subscription" connectionString="Data Source=
XX;database=XX;User ID=XX;Password=X" />  which was missing earlier, but no luck

Comment: I've added some working demonstration code with the minimum amount of code needed to publish an event with NHibernate as subscription storage. I suggest you look at it and compare it to your code to figure out where the problem is. Remember to update the dialect in the config file to whatever version of SQL Server you are using

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, this is very helpful and does make sense. It turns out after removing Assemblies to scan, the application is able to send / publish messages fine. We were scanning types of some events /messages, which were coming from other Nu-get Package in Unobtrusive mode. However  i am not sure if not scanning types may impact the start-up time and why this error occurs, when configure to scan assemblies  ?